# Why @Primary does not work for Kotlin classes sometimes?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have weirdest problem.

I have Java class `A` and I also have Kotlin class `KA` which extends `A`, both are `@Component`s, `KA` is also annotated with `@Primary`.

In some components `KA` is autowired, in others `A` does.
Actually it's even more weird than that, for the same dependent bean between different application launches sometimes `KA` gets autowired, sometimes `A`.

If I rewrite `KA` in Java, then everything works as expected.
Attribute name/constructor parameter name in all the dependent classes is the same: `@Autowired A a;`.

Also it doesn't matter if my Kotlin implementation implements a common interface or extends a base class.

All Kotlin and Java classes live in `src/main/java`.

Kotlin version is `1.1.2-5`, I use jvm8.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the classes you're describing. this excludes any ambuigity.

Comment: @nhaarman, unfortunately I can't, it's part of a proprietary system. But I'll try to create a standalone problematic project. It's really hard to reproduce though, even within our code base the problem is not ubiquitous.

Comment: The problem may be in annotation targets.

Comment: you can simulate your private project problem in examples.